# Biml extension doesn't show up in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: biml

I'm getting my head around how to install Biml extention in VS 2019. I followed the instruction from https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/updates-to-synchronous-autoload-of-extensions-in-visual-studio-2019/ to a T, I mean I clicked "Allow synchronous autoload of extentions", then installed the extention but I still can't create a biml file.
In VS 2017 it works fine but in the higher version it seems really tricky to get it to work.[image]

Comment: Have you installed bids helper? When I installed both in vs2019 BIML extension did not work.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Data tools does not support BIML solution anymore (deprecated).

Download version 3.16

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects

Remove SSDT from current install (Visual Studio Installer)
[image]

[image]

Run the install file downloaded from marketplace:

That should do it.